# Using Join and showing market rank with SUM. not working

Tags: mysql

I have this mySQL query:

```
SELECT market.*, market_chain.* FROM market
        JOIN market_chain
        ON market.mc_id = market_chain.mc_id
```

This is working fine.
"market" table also contains a field named "market_id".
I have another table named "market_ranking" which is in a relation with "market" table by market_id.
What i want is to show each result from my previous query + its market ranking average.

Consider that sometimes market_review doesn't contain ranking for a specific market_id
market_review.mr_rank is the rank for the market. (just numbers from 1 to 5)
I tried:

```
 SELECT market.*, market_chain.*, SUM(market_review.mr_rank) FROM market
            JOIN market_chain
            ON market.mc_id = market_chain.mc_id
            INNER JOIN market_review
            ON market_review.market_id = market.market_id
```

This results in incorrect view and everything is messed up. also i don't really get the average rank.

I hope i made my question clear enough.

Comment: mySQL [extends the group by clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html). you may need to specifiy the fields you want to group on or the system will return a "RANDOM" value from the list.  "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one:

```
SELECT market.*, market_chain.*, SUM(market_review.mr_rank), AVG(market_review.mr_rank) FROM market
LEFT JOIN market_chain
ON market.mc_id = market_chain.mc_id
LEFT JOIN market_review
ON market_review.market_id = market.market_id
GROUP BY market.market_id
```

if it does not help, provide some data please or sqlfiddle would be perfect.

Comment: It did work.. also didn't know about AVG in MYSQL.. Thanks alot! I guess the group by of market.market_id did the job. strange because i thought i tried that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from the question, but it sounds like there can be multiple rows in `market_review` that have the same value of `market_id`. That is, it's a one-to-many relationship between `market` and `market_review`.

One approach to getting the "average rank" from `market_review` is to use an inline view to calculate the average for each `market_id`. It makes more sense we'd want to use the `AVG` aggregate function, rather than `SUM` aggregate.

We can join the results from the inline view to the original query. Since it sounds like it's possible for there to be no rows in `market_review` for every `market_id` returned by the original query, we'll want to make that an "outer" join.

Something like this:

```
 SELECT m.*
      , c.*
      , a.avg_mr_rank
   FROM market m
   JOIN market_chain c
     ON c.mc_id = m.mc_id
   LEFT
   JOIN ( SELECT r.market_id
               , AVG(r.mr_rank) AS avg_mr_rank
            FROM market_review r
           GROUP BY r.market_id
        ) a
     ON a.market_id = m.market_id
  ORDER BY m.market_id
```

If you want SUM of mr_rank rather than AVG, just replace AVG with SUM.

There are several other query patterns that will return an equivalent result. For example, we could do the "outer join" to market_review, and then a GROUP BY market_id on the entire result set. It's also possible to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. Each of those statements is going to exhibit different performance characteristics.

But the query above comes closest to "keep the original query" and "add average rank".

A query that includes a correlated subquery in the SELECT list usually doesn't perform as well.

```
 SELECT m.*
      , c.*
      , ( SELECT AVG(r.mr_rank)
            FROM market_review r
           WHERE r.market_id = m.market_id
        ) AS avg_mr_rank
   FROM market m
   JOIN market_chain c
     ON c.mc_id = m.mc_id
  ORDER BY m.market_id
```

The other option I suggested was doing the "outer join" and using a GROUP BY to collapse the rows; but this approach uses a non-standard MySQL extension to GROUP BY that will throw an error in other databases, and is the source of confusion and consternation for the uninitiated.

I don't recommend this, but this would also return the specified result, assuming that `market_id` is the primary key or is unique in `market`, and assuming that MySQL sql_mode doesn't include ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY)

```
 SELECT m.*
      , c.*
      , AVG(r.mr_rank) AS avg_mr_rank
   FROM market m
   JOIN market_chain c
     ON c.mc_id = m.mc_id
   LEFT
   JOIN market_review r
     ON r.market_id = m.market_id
  GROUP BY m.market_id
  ORDER BY m.market_id
```